# Как связать число с нужным словом в тексте?

Tags: стилистика

> ***По факту гибели 25 сентября в Нагорно-Карабахской Республике 4 и ранения 16 военнослужащих заведено уголовное дело.***

Как отредактировать текст так, чтобы было ясно, что цифра 4 относится к слову "гибель"? А то как-то нескладно получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведено уголовное дело по факту недавнего убийства противником 4 и ранения 16 армянских военнослужащих в Карабахе.

Answer (score 2):

Написать прописью: "*По факту гибели 25 сентября в Нагорно-Карабахской Республике четырёх и ранения шестнадцати военнослужащих заведено уголовное дело*".

Дополнение (если вообще нужно редактирование). По факту происшествия 25 сентября в Нагорно-Карабахской Республике с гибелью 4 и ранением 16 военнослужащих заведено уголовное дело.

*по факту происшествия* — 80 примеров в Нацкорпусе РЯ в *газетном* корпусе.

Comment: Этот вариант еще хуже получился.

Comment: Hermit,при таком варианте получается, что уголовное дело завили вместе с погибшими.

Comment: Откати "дополнение" - первая формулировка самая акуратная и русская - и получи +1

Comment: Какое дополнение?

Answer (score 1):

> По факту гибели 4 и ранения 16 военнослужащих 25 сентября в Нагорно-Карабахской Республике заведено уголовное дело.

Возможно и такое оформление, я думаю.

Comment: Дата в Вашем варианте к чему относится — к происшествию или к открытию уголовного дела?

Comment: Да, здесь дата действительно может относиться как к происшествию, так и к открытию уголовного дела.

Answer (score 0):

А если так оформить?

> В Нагорно-Карабахской Республике заведено уголовное дело по факту гибели четырёх и ранения шестнадцати военнослужащих 25 сентября.

Comment: Артем, если оформить так, то получится, что дело заведено в Карабахе, а цифра 4 можно отнести к ранению. Который день ломаю голову, ничего не придумал. Дословный перевод звучит так: В Нагорном Карабахе недавно в результате обстрела со стороны противника 4 погибших и 16 раненных военнослужащих по факту случившегося заведено уголовное дело.  Такая конструкция используется в армянском. А тот перевод, который нужно отредактировать тоже переводили армянские переводчики.

Comment: Да, правда, получается так, что дело заведено в Карабахе, но четвёрка как раз относится к гибели.